# iPhone camera application running fine in iPhone but crashing in iPod

Tags: iphone, memory, warnings, ipod-touch

i made an iPhone app that uses camera. It works fine in iPhone, no memory warnings at all. It is also running on iPod touch 4G but gives memory warnings and crashes after some time after getting level 2 warning.
If someone can point me the possible reason for this. Thanks.

Comment: You are using too much memory - leaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you are going to fix this is by being able to debug it on the device.  I wrote this blog to explain how to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS, which is what I assume you are getting

http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html

The simplest things to do:

1. Run a Build and Analyze and fix every problem it finds (or at least rewrite it so that B&A doesn't think it's a problem) -- Having a clean B&A is a really good way to making sure you catch these problems early
2. Turn on Zombies and run your program -- this makes the last release sent to an object turn it into a zombie rather than dealloc it.  Your program will leak tons of memory, but if you ever send a message to a zombie it will stop right there and you will see a bug that you need to fix, because in your real version, that would be a crash (sending a message to a dealloced object).

More techniques described at the link

Comment: Thanks Lou the build is stable on both now. i build and analyzed the code and it showed some areas where the memory was leaking.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes on a specific operation or randomly?

if randomly,
use instrument to check your memory leaks and memory usage. It's hard to figure out where the problem lies in without going through all your app.

Comment: thanks. i ran my app on instruments but the total memory allocation never exceeded 3 MB. The thing which is driving me crazy is this that why its running smooth on iPhone but not on iPod Touch.

Comment: @Ammad Hussain Is your iPod Touch and iPhone uses the same version of system? If so, may be you used some undocumented of deprecated API.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. its stable on both now.

Comment: @Ammad may I ask what caused the problem?

Comment: sorry for replying late. i fix some of the memory leaks i found using analyze. One thing coming to my mind is this that the iPhone i have is 3g with iOS 4.2.1, so no multitasking. But iPod has multitasking and other applications were running in the background. the memory occupied by other apps may be causing the app to crash earlier.

Comment: @Ammad multitasking sometimes request special care:)